# Publish module not working on Azure DevOps Pipeline

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, nuget

So after quite a bit of messing around and massaging, I got most of my issues with my lift and shift pipeline other than 2 outstanding things:

1. When run as an azure devops pipeline (when I run it locally it works fine), I get the following error:

```
Publish-Module : The specified module 'xanderu.helpers' with version '0.3.2' was not published because no module with 
that name and version was found in any module directory.
```

2. After a successful build, I want my module to push from the azdo pipeline into a public Github repo (so others can make use of what I've built)

This is a link to the source code that drives this whole thing:
https://github.com/Xander-Rudolph/powershell

Anyone have any ideas as to why the publish module is not able to find the module I've copied into the documents folder when running as a AZDO pipeline?

This is the exact spot where its failing (File .\Public\Publish-ToPSGallery.ps1):

```
        $PublishModulePath = Join-Path $module.FullName /$moduleName
        $UserModulePath = ($env:PSModulePath -split ";")[0]
        ...
        copy-item $PublishModulePath $UserModulePath -force -Recurse
        Publish-Module @moduleParams -RequiredVersion $thisVersion
        Remove-Item (Join-Path $UserModulePath /$moduleName) -Force -Recurse
```

EDIT: After following the suggestion from @WaitingForGuacamole I'm even more confused now. The files are in fact in both places so something about the Microsoft provisioned must be checking a different path...

```
2021-02-22T13:14:26.1798590Z copy from D:\a\1\s\modules\xanderu.helpers\xanderu.helpers to C:\Users\VssAdministrator\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules...
2021-02-22T13:14:26.1907802Z Publish path contents:
2021-02-22T13:14:26.2053090Z 
2021-02-22T13:14:26.2055406Z 
2021-02-22T13:14:26.2057324Z     Directory: D:\a\1\s\modules\xanderu.helpers\xanderu.helpers
2021-02-22T13:14:26.2057953Z 
2021-02-22T13:14:26.2058831Z 
2021-02-22T13:14:26.2062498Z Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                  
2021-02-22T13:14:26.2065623Z ----                -------------         ------ ----                                                                  
2021-02-22T13:14:26.2090344Z d-----        2/22/2021   1:13 PM                private                                                               
2021-02-22T13:14:26.2091497Z d-----        2/22/2021   1:13 PM                public                                                                
2021-02-22T13:14:26.2213533Z -a----        2/22/2021   1:13 PM           8344 xanderu.helpers.psd1                                                  
2021-02-22T13:14:26.2225536Z -a----        2/22/2021   1:13 PM           3986 xanderu.helpers.psm1                                                  
2021-02-22T13:14:26.2236604Z 
2021-02-22T13:14:26.2239849Z 
2021-02-22T13:14:26.2240328Z     Directory: D:\a\1\s\modules\xanderu.helpers\xanderu.helpers\private
2021-02-22T13:14:26.2240554Z 
2021-02-22T13:14:26.2240651Z 
2021-02-22T13:14:26.2242897Z Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                  
2021-02-22T13:14:26.2245357Z ----                -------------         ------ ----                                                                  
2021-02-22T13:14:26.2249485Z -a----        2/22/2021   1:13 PM           8681 New-ModuleTemplate.ps1                                                
2021-02-22T13:14:26.2259995Z -a----        2/22/2021   1:13 PM           2112 New-ScriptTemplate.ps1                                                
2021-02-22T13:14:26.2268743Z 
2021-02-22T13:14:26.2269195Z 
2021-02-22T13:14:26.2270936Z     Directory: D:\a\1\s\modules\xanderu.helpers\xanderu.helpers\public
2021-02-22T13:14:26.2271221Z 
2021-02-22T13:14:26.2271676Z 
2021-02-22T13:14:26.2275692Z Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                  
2021-02-22T13:14:26.2277782Z ----                -------------         ------ ----                                                                  
2021-02-22T13:14:26.2281863Z -a----        2/22/2021   1:13 PM           3386 New-PowershellTemplate.ps1                                            
2021-02-22T13:14:26.2294701Z -a----        2/22/2021   1:13 PM          15800 Publish-ToPSGallery.ps1                                               
2021-02-22T13:14:26.2304889Z User path contents:
2021-02-22T13:14:26.2319844Z 
2021-02-22T13:14:26.2320556Z 
2021-02-22T13:14:26.2322076Z     Directory: C:\Users\VssAdministrator\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules
2021-02-22T13:14:26.2322549Z 
2021-02-22T13:14:26.2323876Z 
2021-02-22T13:14:26.2328059Z Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                  
2021-02-22T13:14:26.2331429Z ----                -------------         ------ ----                                                                  
2021-02-22T13:14:26.2340492Z d-----        2/22/2021   1:14 PM                private                                                               
2021-02-22T13:14:26.2350981Z d-----        2/22/2021   1:14 PM                public                                                                
2021-02-22T13:14:26.2356420Z -a----        2/22/2021   1:13 PM           8344 xanderu.helpers.psd1                                                  
2021-02-22T13:14:26.2369615Z -a----        2/22/2021   1:13 PM           3986 xanderu.helpers.psm1                                                  
2021-02-22T13:14:26.2378132Z 
2021-02-22T13:14:26.2378762Z 
2021-02-22T13:14:26.2380262Z     Directory: C:\Users\VssAdministrator\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\private
2021-02-22T13:14:26.2380559Z 
2021-02-22T13:14:26.2380712Z 
2021-02-22T13:14:26.2387210Z Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                  
2021-02-22T13:14:26.2389867Z ----                -------------         ------ ----                                                                  
2021-02-22T13:14:26.2394106Z -a----        2/22/2021   1:13 PM           8681 New-ModuleTemplate.ps1                                                
2021-02-22T13:14:26.2406799Z -a----        2/22/2021   1:13 PM           2112 New-ScriptTemplate.ps1                                                
2021-02-22T13:14:26.2470087Z 
2021-02-22T13:14:26.2470773Z 
2021-02-22T13:14:26.2472253Z     Directory: C:\Users\VssAdministrator\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\public
2021-02-22T13:14:26.2472928Z 
2021-02-22T13:14:26.2473097Z 
2021-02-22T13:14:26.2479170Z Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                  
2021-02-22T13:14:26.2482022Z ----                -------------         ------ ----                                                                  
2021-02-22T13:14:26.2486251Z -a----        2/22/2021   1:13 PM           3386 New-PowershellTemplate.ps1                                            
2021-02-22T13:14:26.2499805Z -a----        2/22/2021   1:13 PM          15800 Publish-ToPSGallery.ps1                                               
2021-02-22T13:14:26.8343310Z Publish-Module : The specified module 'xanderu.helpers' with version '0.3.3' was not published because no module with 
2021-02-22T13:14:26.8344032Z that name and version was found in any module directory.
2021-02-22T13:14:26.8344599Z At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\xanderu.helpers\0.3.2\public\Publish-ToPSGallery.ps1:137 char:13
2021-02-22T13:14:26.8345194Z +             Publish-Module @moduleParams -RequiredVersion $thisVersio ...
2021-02-22T13:14:26.8345691Z +             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2021-02-22T13:14:26.8346249Z     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (xanderu.helpers:String) [Publish-Module], ArgumentException
2021-02-22T13:14:26.8346842Z     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ModuleNotAvailableLocallyToPublish,Publish-Module
2021-02-22T13:14:26.8347201Z
```

Edit 2:
I set the path to be the C:\Program Files\Windowspowershell path and that seems to bypass the issue, however it throws a nuget 403 error about invalid permissions... something funky still going on here... (see module version 0.4.2)

Comment: It is difficult to investigate this issue using [Microsoft-hosted agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml). I suggest that you use [self-hosted Windows-agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops) to build your project, which will run on local machine and it should work fine. Also you could set pipeline variable system.debug to true then queue build to get debug logs containing detailed build information.

Comment: Please enable **Allow project-scoped builds** option for this NuGet feed as this [doc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/feeds/feed-permissions?view=azure-devops#package-permissions-in-azure-pipelines) stated. Also please grant **Project Collection Build Service (your-collection-name)** and **Your-project-name build service (your-collection-name)** identities required permissions to access to this feed as this [doc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/access-tokens?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#manage-build-service-account-permissions) stated.

Comment: Wallezzi, thanks for the links to those docs but I did actually have that setup already. The 403 errors were related to my own stupidity... changed the PSGallery key and forgot to update the pipeline var. I wanted to make sure this script worked for microsoft hosts because the module is specifically for using AZDO pipelines as a lift and shift powershell CI/CD pipeline (so nothing customized, like runtime agents)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was actually much simpler than I was making it. The suggestion for WaitingForGuacamole did expose what the issue was. For some reason the user directory is not a valid location for the publish-module command. After updating the module to use the C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell path, I started seeing the 403 error but that wasn't actually an error for the AZDO repo it was because I had reset my PSGallery key and hadn't updated the pipeline param.

Answer (score 1):

I'd add this as a comment but it won't allow block formatting, so:

Try adding the following to your script after the `Copy-Item` step to help diagnose and resolve:

```
Write-Host "Publish path contents:"
Get-ChildItem $PublishModulePath -Recurse
Write-Host "User path contents:"
Get-ChildItem $UserModulePath -Recurse
```

This will help you to see if the module you want to publish is actually where you think it is, and make necessary adjustments. Also, it would be useful to see the contents of `@moduleParams` in the question.

Comment: This did actually help. I identified which module path seems to be the right one and after some trial and error, the C:\Program files folder is where it needed to go (which is a little dangerous IMO)